Is it possible to connect 6 two-wire RTDs to ADS124S08 Analog to Digital Converter using the following schematic
I have connected 6 two-wire RTDs to a ADS124S08 Analog to Digital Converter. My requiernments are to connect as many RTDs as possible to the chip with least amount of extra equipment and to achieve a mix between accuracy and number of RTDs
The attached image is a schematic of 6 Two Wire RTDs connected to a ADS124S08 Analog to Digital Converter. I would like to know the following things about my idea:

Will the AINCOM pin acting ac IDAC1 be complying with the load of 6 RTDs?
Will any of the readings of the RTDs be distorted? If yes, then to what extent will it be filterable by any hardware or software?
Is there any chance of any unexpected error which I have not predicted yet?
Is there any other way/schematic to achieve this objective?



It should function with the correct choice of configuration and resistor values for the desired resistance range of the RTDs.
The compliance voltage of the current sources is listed in the datasheet and you should pay attention to it. It's different for different currents. You will want to accommodate the maximum resistance of each RTD plus the voltage drop across the reference resistor, which should be something like 1V.
Pay attention to the "Absolute input voltage" limits, which depend on the PGA gain setting. I suggest checking this calculation carefully once you decide the final currents and resistor values.
Note that the entire device will cease to function if any of the 12 RTD connections are open or a sensor fails open.
Also you've directly connected IC pin AINCOM to what appears to be field wiring, which is considered a fairly bold move in my circles.
